# If I overpaid a travel agency for a ticket, can I claim some money back? How?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, refunds

I reserved a ticket with an agency, at that time the ticket was at $750 and I paid it for the reservation, but I didn't receive a confirmation from Emirates that my ticket had been booked. Just a week later, Emirates advertised a promotion with ticket price dropping to $540 and that's when I received a confirmation from Emirates that my ticket has been booked. It's clear the agency bought me a ticket for $540.

Comment: How did you pay for this ticket?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16600/do-these-airline-companies-offer-any-refund-policies-for-when-the-ticket-price-d

Comment: @audionuma I don't think it is a duplicate

Comment: @Berwyn : I mentioned 'possible' ... and tagged it as duplicate so that it can be sorted out.

Comment: Fair enough @audionuma but the linked question is about price reductions after purchase. The OP is claiming the TA bought the ticket post-reduction price and charged the OP pre-reduction price.

Comment: Well, depending on the OP jurisdiction, the time he/she payed for the ticket might be considered as the purchasing date, even if the booking confirmation came later. Let's see what comes up.

Comment: Yes, but per IATA regulations, a Travel Agent isn't allowed to pay for a flight using their own credit card, they must use the traveller's. Hence my question to the OP.

Comment: Just because you got the confirmation the same day as Emirates started a sale doesn't mean the TA bought the ticket that day.  You need to look at the fare details on the booking to determine what airfare was paid.

Comment: Thanks guys and @Tom. I only received a mail from the TA when I made a reservation. So can I go there and ask for the fare details on the booking as well? I paid $750 in cash

Comment: Go to the TA and ask for ticket details including locator code, ticket number, ticketing date and fare basis. If you don't feel comfortable that they are telling you the truth, you can call the airline and ask for the ticketing date for the ticket you have.

Comment: Sorry, reservation date is also relevant.

Comment: @ShelterEnesiaChimhau Assuming that the travel agency waited a week to actually book the ticket: If the airline had raised the price in the meantime, would you have found it acceptable from the travel agency to claim the price difference from you? If you would not find that acceptable: Why do you assume that you can claim any money back from the travel agency?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about consumer protection law in some unspecified country, not about travel. Further, it's unclear that the premise ("I overpaid") is even true.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you intend to prove that the agent bought you the same ticket (the basis of your claim); and pocketed the difference.

Consider the following:

1. It is normal for airlines to offer cheaper fares on their website than agents; or hold different promotions that are not offered to agents.
2. The fare type/class/code may be different; you may not be comparing apples to apples; even if both tickets are for the same class of travel.
3. Rates that are available to individuals through direct booking are not always available to agents.
4. The agent would have to have advance knowledge of a booking; hold your reservation till that date, ensure that they were able to book that reservation in order to take advantage. A highly unlikely scenario.

I personally have had to pay a premium for booking through agents many times.

Comment: Once the OP find the ticket details, they call the airline and find out what was paid. Except with certain consolidator fares this isn't going to be a secret.